# ConcurrentModificationException without modifying object

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, concurrentmodification

I've got the following piece of code that is causing a ConcurrentModificationException. I'm not modifying the `products` object at all,

```
List<Product> products = Product.findActiveByFilter(filters);
Set<Long> temp = new HashSet<Long>();
List<Product> resultSetTemp = new ArrayList<Product>();
for (Product product : products) { // << Exception points to this
    if(!temp.contains(product.getId())){
        temp.add(product.getId());
        resultSetTemp.add(product);
    }
}
products.clear();
products.addAll(resultSetTemp);
```

I've seen this exception pop-up several times, but I cannot reproduce it (it happens randomly).

`Product.findActiveByFilter` is a method that returns a new instance of a `List<Product>` that has been build from a cached `List<Product>`.

**Edit:** I've found a way to reproduce the error. The code is called when a client wants the products (its a webshop), and the website loads more items when the client scrolls down. This triggers the exception (as the server is not-yet done responding with the products, and gets another call for it). Race conditions, fun!

Comment: Seems like some other thread tries to modify it

Comment: Which line does the exception happen on?

Comment: @serejja Wouldn't that be weird? The `List<Product> products` is a local variable

Comment: @BoristheSpider The for loop (line 4)

Comment: Can you post code for `Product.findActiveByFilter` please

Comment: P.S. why not use a `Map<Long, Product>` to store your results rather than keeping two collections in sync?

Comment: @chris No can do, it's a huge function with many checks (for every filter type it checks if it has already filtered something before, if so, filter the filtered. Else, filter the cached list)

Comment: @BoristheSpider I haven't made this code from scratch; it's from a different developer. Shouldn't create a conflict tho.

Comment: Okay. Reason I asked is, are you 100% sure it's returning a *copy* of the cached list and not the cached list itself? Because if it's the cached list itself, and your code gets run in two different places simultaneously (=concurrently), you will get the exception you're having

Comment: Try to create a new List and work with it. `List<Product> tmpProducts = new ArrayList<Product>(products);`

Comment: @chris There could be a case of that; changed the code of `findActiveByFilter` to return a new instance of `List<Product>(products)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some said already, it was caused by a seperate tread 'modifying' `products` (as it was a cached instance). 
I've changed the implementation of `Product.findActiveByFilter` to return a `new ArrayList<Product>(products);` instead of a reference to the cached value, when no filters are applied (thus no filtered result is given back).

```
public static List<Product> findActiveByFilter(ArrayList<FilterPair> filters) {
    List<Product> products = getCachedAllProductsByFirstSupplier();

    if (products == null) {
        products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    if(filters.size() > 0) {
        List<Product> productsFiltered = new ArrayList<Product>(products);
        // ... MANY checks here for the filters ...

        return productsFiltered;
    }

    return new ArrayList<Product>(products); // Do not give cached copy, was 'return products;'
}
```

There were 2 calls to the findActiveByFilter, called by the website. The first one did include a filter, but the second one did not (so the first one was still busy, while the second one returned directly).

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer back. Glad it worked! Seems like @serejja was right :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an iterator?

```
List<Product> products = Product.findActiveByFilter(filters);
Set<Long> temp = new HashSet<Long>();
List<Product> resultSetTemp = new ArrayList<Product>();

Iterator ite = products.iterator();

while (ite.hasNext()) {

    Product product = ite.next();

    if(!temp.contains(product.getId())){

        temp.add(product.getId());
        resultSetTemp.add(product);
    }
}
products.clear();
products.addAll(resultSetTemp);
```

**EDIT:** Just saw your update. In light of that, this probably won't solve your problem.

Comment: I don't think that will resolve the issue. When we do foreach loop an iterator is used.